shape key driver is working on 2 axis simultaneously (i don't want that)
I'm trying to make a shape key (for a furrowed brow) that activates based on Z location of a control bone. It activates when needed, however, it ALSO activates when i move that bone on an X-axis too, which i obviously don't want. Not only is it not intended, it also messes up the shape key that i ACTUALLY want to activate through X location of that same control bone. I'm using the move tool with the arrows, so it definitely doesn't move on Z-axis in this scenario, only on X-axis. What could've gone wrong and how can i fix it?
edit: here are my settings. i tried seemingly the same steps in a different file and it didn't happen there. i also tried switching to averaged value, but it didn't help. I also tried remaking the driver from zero and clearing bone roll.



I think you need to select Pose space but I’m not sure. Local space might be using the axes of the entire object instead of the bone.

I figured it out, I think! It turned out that I was using the global world axis instead of the actual local axis of that bone. Once I changed the bone to be vertical and used its local axis for the driver, everything started working correctly.
